# Why is my target plattform not supported by my project?

Tags: c#, dll, xamarin.android, x86

Android Project and a dynamic library written in c++.
Now I get the error that my native refernece target platform x86 is not supoorted by my project. The only abi that is supported is armeabi-v7a. 
the only .so file that is being ignored is also the one in the x86 file.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I guess I need to change the configuration to Debug and change settings?
[image]

I still get the error that my debug is disabled in android properties :/

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Android **Project>Properties>Android Options**

On the bottom right you will have the **Advanced** settings button, click it

In the supported architectures select x86 as shown in below image:

[image]

Comment: But now I get other warnings, see above I have edited my post :/

Comment: You can ignore the no debug symbol was found warning for now, And secondly do not target `armeabi` as it's going to be removed soon!

Comment: I still get the error that my debug is disabled in android properties :/

Comment: Okay do one thing go to **Build>Configuration Manager** and check if Android projects deploy checkbox is checked or not!!

Comment: I have posted another screenshot above. Somehow I cannot change my Deploy chechbox for my Library. Or did you mean my Android project?

Comment: I meant your Android project only not the library!

Comment: Can you read what the output window has to say!? maybe you might find your issue there!?

Comment: As you can see above, my output says that my library  is not found and also that my .so files are 32 bit instead of 64 bit

Comment: Okay np if you don't mind we can connect on sunday i will take a look